# Unidentified Whitespace

Tags: r, string, text

I am working on a text-mining project using the seven Harry Potter books. There is an R package that contains the text of the books. In this package, each book is a vector, and each chapter is a string contained in the vector.

While prepping the strings for my analysis, I keep running into some sort of whitespace that I can't identify, and can't figure out how to remove. This is illustrated by the following code:

```
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github("bradleyboehmke/harrypotter")
require(harrypotter)

temp <- substr(philosophers_stone[1], 0, 31)
temp

temp <- gsub(" ", "", temp)
temp

temp <- gsub("[\t\n\r\v\f]", "", temp)
temp
```

The output of the code is as follows:

```
temp <- substr(philosophers_stone[1], 0, 31)
temp
# [1] "THE BOY WHO LIVED　　Mr. and Mrs."
temp <- gsub(" ", "", temp)
temp
# [1] "THEBOYWHOLIVED　　Mr.andMrs."
temp <- gsub("[\t\n\r\v\f]", "", temp)
temp
# [1] "THEBOYWHOLIVED　　Mr.andMrs."
temp <- gsub("&nbsp;", "", temp)
temp
# [1] "THEBOYWHOLIVED　　Mr.andMrs."
```

Can anyone help me figure out what this thing is, and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Could you add your `sessionInfo()`? It appears there's some platform-dependency issue with your bug as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use `charToRaw`:

charToRaw(temp)

```
#  [1] 54 48 45 20 42 4f 59 20 57 48 4f 20 4c 49 56 45 44 e3 80 80 e3 80 80 4d 72 2e 20 61 6e 64 20 4d
# [33] 72 73 2e
```

Each element here corresponds to a character (basically). We can deduce that the troublesome whitespace is `e3 80 80` (repeated twice). According to [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=12288&number=128) that corresponds to an ["ideographic space"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ideographic_space), a space of uniform width (commonly used in fixed-width scripts, e.g. Chinese or Japanese).

Anyway, now we can convert that back with `rawToChar` and `gsub` it away:

```
gsub(rawToChar(as.raw(c('0xe3', '0x80', '0x80'))), '', temp)
# [1] "THE BOY WHO LIVEDMr. and Mrs."
```

(`fixed = TRUE` could be added for speed, but this is not as relevant since you're also axing all other whitespace)

FWIW just using `\s` works for me as well (same for Richard Scriven's other suggestion, `[[:space:]]`):

```
gsub('\\s', '', temp)
# [1] "THEBOYWHOLIVEDMr.andMrs."
```

I guess `\s` is not working for you because of locale or platform issues; from `?regex`:

> `[:space:]`    Space characters: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and **possibly other locale-dependent characters**.
>   [*emphasis mine*]

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Strange-- not sure how the whitespace is defined. But, you could try storing that strange whitespace (characters 18 and 19 in the sample you provided) as a variable and then replacing it in your text like this:

```
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github("bradleyboehmke/harrypotter")
require(harrypotter)

temp <- substr(philosophers_stone[1], 0, 31)
x <- substr(temp, 18, 19)
temp <- gsub(x, "", temp)
temp <- gsub(" ", "", temp)
```

Comment: No problem- hope it helps!